# Same error line multiple times in error log

Tags: java

Could someone explain me what could be the reason for such an error log. When would this be printed. I am not able to understand and this is causing a performance issue in my app.

my error log is like below-

```
at xxx.createBooking(MailEJB3ServiceZipProxy.java:453)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2524)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
    at xxxx.onSelectBooking(Main.java:2603)
```

my catch block code looks like -

```
public void onSelectBooking(){
try{
////     
} catch(ReservationBusinessException ex){
            m_hModuleContainer.setBusy(false);
            List mail = ex.getMailHeader();
            m_hCargoRecordDTO = (CargoRecordDTO)mail.get(0);
            ReservationObserver m_hReservationObserver= new ReservationObserver();
            m_hReservationObserver.setCargoRecordDTO(m_hCargoRecordDTO);
            m_hReservationParameterDTO.setReservationObserver(m_hReservationObserver);
            ExceptionTab exceptionTab = new ExceptionTab(m_hReservationParameterDTO,m_hCargoRecordDTO,ex);
            if ( exceptionTab.isErrorsOverridden() ){
            // set all overridden flags
            m_hCargoRecordDTO.setSoftErrorsAccepted(true);
            m_hCargoRecordDTO.setErrorShown(true);
            m_hMailHeaderDTO.addHtCar(m_hCargoRecordDTO);
            onSelectBooking();**// line 2603**
            }
```

Comment: My guess is that it's because you keep calling the failing method recursively within the catch-clause. Each time it fails again the call will end up on the stack. The first time it fails is on line 2524 and then you call the method again on line 2603 where it keeps failing.

Comment: You are calling the method itself again in catch block causing the infinite execution is method if there is an exception. Can you explain what is the intention of doing this? The first suggestion from us is not to call the method itself again from catch block.

Comment: Presuming the error printed before the first line is **`StackOverflowError`**, it's because you have infinite recursion, where the logic in the `try` block fails with `ReservationBusinessException`, causing the code to **retry infinitely** with a recursive call in line 2603, until the call stack is full.

Comment: The reason for this is that there are multiple records which would fail and to handle all this recursive call is there. Instead of removing this recursive call . How can I handle this?

Comment: The purpose of a catch block is to clean up after a failed try block. You should not be doing things that can fail in your catch block.  Set a flag, and retry after the catch block is finished.

Comment: I checked the looping and usage of this call. Suppose I have 5 records. First time, BI is called, it throws exception and catch is called. it sets the parameters(`m_hCargoRecordDTO.setSoftErrorsAccepted(true);) `. from catch `onSelectBooking()` is called. and then from try again BI is called which works on second record. So for one record the call is only once.It doesn't go in a loop. Is it possible that this could create performance issue ?? same execution is happening. Why the performance is decreasing with every records or loop??

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the error printed before the first line is **`StackOverflowError`**, it's because you have infinite recursion, where the logic in the `try` block fails with `ReservationBusinessException`, causing the code to **retry infinitely** with a recursive call in line 2603, until the call stack is full.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Change the code to use a loop, instead of recursion, to retry, e.g.

   ```java
   public void onSelectBooking() {
       boolean retry;
       do {
           retry = false;
           try {
               ...
           } catch(ReservationBusinessException ex) {
               ...
               retry = true; // instead of recursive call
           }
       } while (retry);
   ```

   The problem with this solution is that the code may never complete, if the cause of the exception isn't resolved.
2. Limit the number of retries. This should be done using a loop like above but with a retry count instead of a boolean, but can still be done using recursion:

   ```java
   private static int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
   public void onSelectBooking() {
       onSelectBooking(0); // first attempt is not a "retry"
   }
   public void onSelectBooking(int retry) {
       try {
           ...
       } catch(ReservationBusinessException ex) {
           if (retry > MAX_RETRIES) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Max. number of retries (" + MAX_RETRIES + ") exceeded: " + ex, ex);
           }
           ...
           onSelectBooking(retry + 1);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I checked the looping and usage of this call. Suppose I have 5 records. First time, BI is called, it throws exception and catch is called. it sets the parameters`(m_hCargoRecordDTO.setSoftErrorsAccepted(true);)` . from catch `onSelectBooking()` is called. and then from try again BI is called which works on second record. So for one record the call is only once.It doesn't go in a loop. Is it possible that this could create performance issue ?? same execution is happening. Why the performance is decreasing with every records or loop??.

Comment: @user1896796 It loops for every failed records, so if you have more records failing than will fill on the call stack, you *will* get a `StackOverflowError`. Rewrite the code to use a loop (#1) to fix that, as long as you are **sure** each invocation will process a different record.